# OpenGL - 2D enemy not rotating to face player

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, 2d, transformation

I am creating a 2D game and at the moment I am trying to rotate my enemy so that it is always facing my player when my player moves. I am using the dot product to calculate the angle to then rotate the enemy, however it is not working. Below is how I am working out the angle...

```
//calculating the angle
float numerator = (player.x*enemy.x)+(player.y*enemy.y);
float denominator = sqrt((player.x*player.x)+(player.y*player.y))*sqrt((enemy.x*enemy.x)+(enemy.y*enemy.y));
float angle = acos(numerator/denominator);
```

This is also recalculated within an update function.

Below is how I display my enemy...

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(enemy.x, enemy.y, 0);
     glRotatef(angle,0,0,1);
     glTranslatef(-enemy.x, -enemy.y, 0);
     enemy.drawCircle(enemy.x,enemy.y, enemy.radius);
glPopMatrix();
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: I'm also going to strongly, *strongly* recommend that you convert your codebase to Modern OpenGL, as trying to do this stuff in OpenGL 1.x is a nightmare that leads to issues like this. [This is a good site for learning modern OpenGL](http://www.learnopengl.com/#!Introduction)

Comment: It's not rotating at all.... So I changed it to rotate angle*180/PI to see what that does and it rotates to look at my player sometimes depending on the players position however the majority of the time it doesn't rotate correctly

Comment: And thank you I plan on progressing to modern OpenGL at some point but want to try and solve this problem first because as far as I'm aware I'm applying the maths correctly/:

Comment: Have you tried incrementally rotating around the object to see how it reacts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have an error in geometry formula. You actually found an angle between vector of an enemy and vector of a player.

What you might need is an angle of a their difference vector

```
double dx = enemy.x - player.x;
double dy = enemy.y - player.y;
double ang = atan2(dy, dx);
```

Comment: I would also recommend you to define a Point struct (Same as vector) or use one that is already written. It is very convenient to have something like `(a - b).ang`. Consider [accepting](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png) the answer if it helped.